# Preg match pattern that does not starts with @

Tags: php, regex

I have following pattern to match {{ $name }} block

```
#{{2}(?:[^{}]*|(?R))+}{2}#
```

If i improve above to ignore pattern that does not with **@**

```
#^(?:@){{2}(?:[^{}]*|(?R))+}{2}#
```

then above matches

```
{{$abc}} @{{$name}}
```

but not

```
@{{$name}} {{$abc}}
```

There can be any number of block per line but block starts with @ should not be matched.

Comment: Are you trying to match an email address?

Comment: So `@{{$name}}` must not be matched but `{{$abc}}` should match?

Comment: @anubhava yes it should match only if does not starts with @

Comment: @this.lau_ no, i am trying to match {{ }} block

Comment: why `(?R)` ? could be there more nested items like `{{{$abcd}}}` ?

Comment: Now, the question is: do you need to match `{{$abc@{{xyz}} }}`? If yes, a  lookbehind alone [won't be enough](https://regex101.com/r/3kuT0I/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes {{$abc@{{xyz}} }} should match

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookbehind in your original regex:

```
(?<!@){{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))+}}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XL8m0L/2)

`(?<!@)` is negative lookbehind assertion to fail the match when you have `@` just before `{{...}}`.

Comment: Cool, i was trying by ^ appending at start

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a negative lookbehind `(?<!@)` , wrap the rest with a capturing group and replace `(?R)` with `(?1)`:

```
(?<!@)({{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*}})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3kuT0I/2).

If you just use a negative lookahead, it will also be recursed with `(?R)` and `{{$abc@{{xyz}} }}` like substrings  won't get matched.

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/mQACJZ):

```
$re = '~(?<!@)({{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*}})~';
$str = '@{{$name}} {{$abc{{xyz}} }} {{$abc@{{xyz}} }}';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
// => Array ( [0] => {{$abc{{xyz}} }} [1] => {{$abc@{{xyz}} }} )
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
**Try this one**
you must use [^@] to avoid @

/^[^@][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,}$/
```